# Java Sockets Not Working Over LAN?

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I'm trying to add multiplayer capabilities to a game I've created. I've read through Java's [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/) on sockets, but find myself still unable to achieve the functionality I desire. In a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28517906/java-socket-is-not-working-on-lan), another user seemed to experience the very same issues that I am.

In my case...

- I am running the two programs given directly on the Java tutorial.
- When I run them both on the same computer, they work flawlessly.
- When I run the server program on my OSX machine (with root) and the client program on a W7 machine, I continuously get IOExceptions --  the client machine cannot reach the server machine even on the same port (I used 9355 for both).
- When I run the server program on my W7 machine and the client program on my OSX machine (with root), I still get IOExceptions.

Some additional information...

- Running `System.out.println(serverSocket.getInetAddress());` in the server program returns `0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0` on both machines.

From

```
  System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to " + hostName);
  e.printStackTrace();
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
```

I get

```
Couldn't get I/O for the connection to 192.168.0.37
Operation timed out
java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at Main.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:17)
Operation timed out
```

*Why might I need to disable the firewall on either the client or server machine? Hasn't Java opened a socket for incoming data? Why does the tutorial make it out to be so simple if it's yet to work?*

Comment: Does your client use the OSX machine's ip address to connect? The ``0.0.0.0`` information is totally useless...

Comment: You continuously get *what* IOExceptions? Why are you jumping to conclusions without presenting all the data? 'Why might I need to disable the firewall?' You mightn't. 'Hasn't Java opened a socket?' Yes it has. 'Why does the tutorial make it out to be so simple ...?' It is. If you expect help here you will need to present an answerable problem, rather than just a list of questions based on guesswork based in turn on concealed evidence.

Comment: @f1sh From what I've read elsewhere, `0.0.0.0` means that the server program is connected to all network interfaces on the server machine. It was even mentioned in the similar post I linked.

Comment: @EJP My apologies; I've included some additional information.

Comment: @user5705019 that's true. That's why it holds no information, because this gets printed on all machines. It really looks like your operating system is blocking incoming connections for whatever reasons.

Answer (score 2):

```
ConnectException: operation timed out
```

That indicates either that the host is down or a firewall problem.

> Why might I need to disable the firewall

Because it is blocking inbound connections. You don't need to disable it completely: you need to open the port you're listening on in the server firewall.

> Hasn't Java opened a socket

Yes, and that's how you got the 0.0.0.0: it's the listening address of that `ServerSocket`.

Comment: The whole purpose of a firewall is to block incoming connections, which is what the OP is trying to do, so it shouldn't be surprising that the firewall needs to be opened to not block the desired port. +1

Comment: I've completely disabled my router's IPv4 firewall yet the connections still aren't going through.

Comment: Have you disabled the firewall on the computer running the server portion of your software?

Comment: @user5705019 Are you still getting 'operation timed out', or a different message?

Comment: I switched to a different environment (different router) and it works fine now. It must have something to do with this CenturyLink router/modem combo... *-.-